# How to deploy new versions of software applications while allow old versions running?

Tags: deployment, continuous-delivery

Let me use Wine as an example. Wine on Ubuntu uses the server-client architecture. 
While I am using wine on Ubuntu to run some .exe programs, I upgrade wine.
While I am able to continuously running the already running .exe programs, I can't start to run new .exe programs after upgrading wine, because I can't start a new version of client to work with the old version of wine server that is still running.

Generally speaking, if  a software application allows client and server of different versions to run together, is that ability called [rolling upgrade, rolling release,  continuous delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_release), or something else? (In some Linux distributions, such as Gentoo, which is said to use rolling release, have no discrete version, while Ubuntu does. But here an software application with the ability that I describe here have discrete versions, so I am confused.)

How is that ability done in deployment?

Does it apply only to client-server software? (I read https://www.quora.com/What-is-meant-by-a-rolling-upgrade-in-software-development). Specifically,

- Is server upgraded, while client of older version is still running?
- Does this require running multiple instances of server and move receiving and handling client requests   between server  instances?
- Does this require the server of new version be compatible with client of old version? (In case of Wine, that is not true?)
- Does client still need to be upgraded, but can be upgraded only after it voluntarily exit, or not necessarily, since the server of new version can work with client of old version?

Does the ability apply to software applications with single process architecture (no server-client split)?
If a software application is single process, when upgrade its version while it is running,

- is it correct that we never have to worry about its down time, because its older version is still running as a process in memory, without being affected by the deployed new version replacement?
- How can we make the new version  seamlessly  replace the old version?

Thanks.

Comment: "Generally speaking, if a software application allows client and server of different versions to run together, is that ability called" Having WIndows :P - jokes aside, See [Deployment Strategies Defined](http://blog.itaysk.com/2017/11/20/deployment-strategies-defined)

Comment: not sure what you are asking. obvs if you do the version switch fast enough it will seem like its continuously running regardless of its architecture

Comment: @Ewan What is "version switch"? How would you do it fast enough?

Comment: Kubernetes calls this feature [version skew](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/): you can separately update components separately, as long as the versions of all components are close enough (e.g. within one minor version). That way, a running system can be updated without downtime.

Comment: The question is way too broad. The technology to update a process running on a computer is substantially different from updating a cloud service.